# Puppet: err:/Exec/returns: change from notrun to 0 failed: Command exceeded timeout

Tags: linux, puppet

I am trying to install Nagios on my servers using puppet and my custom shell script.Every thing works fine but I see an error in the end of puppet script execution as below :

```
[root@localhost tmp]# /usr/local/bin/puppet --verbose nagiosscript.pp
....
.... Lines of verbose output
....
info: Scope(Class[main]): installing Nagios agent in /usr/local/nagios
info: Applying configuration version '1016779459'
notice: /Stage[main]//Exec[/tmp/check_server.sh]/returns: executed successfully
notice: /Stage[main]//File[/tmp/temporary_mount]/ensure: created
notice: /Stage[main]//Exec[mount]/returns: executed successfully
notice: /Stage[main]//Exec[retrieve_nagios_install_script]/returns: executed successfully
notice: /Stage[main]//File[/var/tmp/nagios_install.sh]/mode: mode changed '644' to '700'

err: /Stage[main]//Exec[/var/tmp/nagios_install.sh]/returns: change from notrun to 0 failed: Command exceeded timeout at /tmp/nagiosscript.pp:34

notice: Finished catalog run in 332.42 seconds
```

I am not sure what this error means but nagios installation went well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a known **[FACT](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=859407)**

By default puppet waits for 300 secs to finish the job if it does not then only you see the error like above . You can define **[timeout](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/type.html)** value in your puppet script. 
use following in your puppet script

```
timeout => 0,
```

From Puppet document:

```
Timeout
The maximum time the command should take. If the command takes longer than the timeout, 
the command is considered to have failed and will be stopped. 
The timeout is specified in seconds. The default timeout is 300 seconds and 
you can set it to 0 to disable the timeout.
```